# How to Stop Chef Recipe from Running When Already Complete

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I made a recipe for vagrant that installs phpunit, however it keeps failing when I use vagrant halt then vagrant up.

```
execute "discover phpunit" do
  command "pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de"
  action :run
end

execute "config phpunit" do
  command "pear config-set auto_discover 1"
  action :run
end

execute "install phpunit" do
  command "pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
  action :run
end
```

I get:

```
[default] [Thu, 29 Mar 2012 14:39:57 -0700] ERROR: execute[discover phpunit] (phpunit::default line 39) has had an error
[Thu, 29 Mar 2012 14:39:57 -0700] ERROR: execute[discover phpunit] (/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/phpunit/recipes/default.rb:39:in `from_file') had an error:
execute[discover phpunit] (phpunit::default line 39) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de ----
STDOUT: Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is already initialized
```

Comment: Which version of vagrant are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what is happening is this script is being run every time `vagrant up` is executed.

You probably want something like this:

```
execute "discover phpunit" do
  command "pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de"
  action :run
  not_if "which phpunit"
end
```

Just make sure `phpunit` is in you `$PATH`

Comment: That's true.  Good one!  Here's another question: how can I make it exit the recipe if it has phpunit?

Comment: @NathanBrakk there's really no way (that I know of) to "exit" a recipe since it is basically a procedural script

Comment: In other words: It is up to you to make your cookbook idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably set the not_if to

```
not_if { File.exists?('/path/to/phpunit')
```

rather than relying on it getting found in $PATH.